# expressions in query using PIVOT command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am attempting to pull data from a table that includes a percentage value based on 2 different values - the nbr of records touched/the total nbr of records.  I want a rolling monthly total.  I have a query that seems to be on the right track but there's an obvious flaw so I'm hoping to get some help.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    Area_NM,
    [1] AS Jan,
    [2] AS Feb,
    [3] AS Mar,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS May,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Oct,
    [11] AS Nov,
    [12] AS Dec
 FROM
 (select Area_NM, month(Closed_DT) as TMonth, (100. * 

    (
        select COUNT(*) from T_AREA AS DISP
        WHERE P.Area_NM = DISP.Area_NM AND DISP.Branch_MKT = 'NORTHEAST' AND DISP.About <> 'Branch' AND DISP.CAP_TXT IS NOT NULL
    )  
     /  
    (
        select sum(count(*)) over () from T_AREA AS TOT
        WHERE P.Area_NM = TOT.Area_NM AND TOT.Branch_MKT = 'NORTHEAST' AND TOT.About <> 'Branch' 
    )) as perc
    from T_AREA AS P
    WHERE P.Branch_MKT = 'NORTHEAST' AND P.About <> 'Branch'

    ) source    
PIVOT
(    
SUM(perc) **OBVIOUS ERROR
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
   ) AS pvtMonth
```

The results should look something like this:

```
Area Name | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | ......
____________________________________________
Arlington    44%   0%    0%    0%......
```

(where Arlington had 9 from TOT and 4 from DISP in JAN, 0 in DISP for the rest of the months)
The actual results are numbers, just not accurate percentages.

The error appears to be in the way the `PIVOT` command is called. Since I've already run the expression, I technically do not need the `SUM`, I just need the value of the expression. Correct?

EDIT:
Adding some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [T_AREA](
[Case_NBR] [varchar](18) NULL,
[About] [varchar](15) NULL,
[CAP_TXT] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Complaint_TYP] [varchar](11) NULL,
[Branch_MKT] [varchar](9) NULL,
[Branch_DIV] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Area_NM] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Branch_NM] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Closed_DT] [datetime] NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO [T_AREA]
[Case_NBR],[About],[CAP_TXT],[UPDT_DT],[Complaint_TYP],[Branch_MKT],[Branch_DIV], [Area_NM],[Branch_NM],[Closed_DT])
VALUES
('05/21/2014-1577309','Branch Teammate',NULL,'Operational','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','DC N Arlington GWM Area','1275 K STREET','5/23/2014  11:44:34 AM'),
('05/21/2014-1577382','Branch Teammate','No Action','Service','NORTHEAST','North and South Carolina','Hickory Salisbury NCSC Area','STATESVILLE BOULEVARD','5/27/14 3:05 PM'),
('05/21/2014-1577949','Branch Teammate',NULL,'Operational','NORTHEAST','Total Virginia','Richmond E Henrico VA Area','TENTH AND MAIN','5/21/14 6:41 PM'),
('05/22/2014-1578740','Branch Teammate','No Action','Service','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','Baltimore Harford GWM Area','WATERVIEW TOWN CENTER','5/22/14 8:58 AM'),
('05/22/2014-1579248','Branch Teammate','No Action','Operational','NORTHEAST','North and South Carolina','Winston Salem NCSC Area','MEDICAL PARK','4/27/14 9:03 AM'),
('05/22/2014-1579250','Branch Teammate','No Action','Service','NORTHEAST','Total Tennessee','Nashville Rutherford TN Area','MURFREESBORO ROAD','4/22/14 5:04 PM'),
('05/22/2014-1579578','Branch Teammate','No Action','Operational','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','Alexandria S Arling GWM Area','LANDMARK','5/22/14 6:11 PM'),
('05/22/2014-1579605','Branch Teammate',NULL,'Operational','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','Baltimore Harford GWM Area','NORTH CHARLES','5/27/14 10:36 AM'),
('05/22/2014-1579609','Branch Teammate',NULL,'Operational','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','North PG GWM Area','BLADENSBURG','6/3/14 9:25 PM'),
('05/23/2014-1580473','Branch Teammate','No Action','Operational','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','Fairfax Prince Wm GWM Area','MONTCLAIR','6/29/14 5:12 PM'),
('05/23/2014-1580518','Branch Teammate',NULL,'Service','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','S Montgomery GWM Area','OLNEY','6/23/14 10:42 AM'),
('05/23/2014-1580667','Branch Teammate','No Action','Operational','NORTHEAST','North and South Carolina','Greater S Charlotte NCSC Area','HILLTOP-MONROE','5/29/14 10:09 AM'),
('05/23/2014-1580687','Branch Teammate',NULL,'Operational','NORTHEAST','Gr Washington and Maryland','North PG GWM Area','ARDWICK-ARDMORE','3/23/14 12:18 PM'),
('05/23/2014-1580784','Branch Teammate',NULL,'Operational','NORTHEAST','North and South Carolina','Hickory Salisbury NCSC Area','STATESVILLE BOULEVARD','6/28/14 3:28 PM'),
('05/23/2014-1581167','Branch Teammate','No Action','Operational','NORTHEAST','Total Tennessee','Memphis TN Area','POPLAR & HIGHLAND','5/29/14 10:38 AM');
```

Comment: You tagged this with both MySQL and SQL Server, what database are you using?  MySQL doesn't have PIVOT, so that would be an issue.  If you run the subquery (excluding the pivot stuff) - does it work?

Comment: It's SQL Server 2008.  Yes the sub query does work, excluding the pivot.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting with the query?

Comment: There actually is not an error, just the results are skewed.  I am expecting this result:  Area Name | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | ......

Arlington 44% 0% 0% 0%......   BUT I get percentages that are off.  (more like) Arlington 156% 65% 36% 17%......                 I guess I'm confused because when I run the subQuery, I get the correct percentage results.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question with your tables, sample data and then the desired results - or even better create a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I'm having trouble creating a fiddle.  Does this sample data work (NOTE - I changed the name of the table to T_AREA):

Answer (score 0):

After much trouble shooting I figured out the error, it was a few.  I will list below:
1. Needed DISTINCT in the main query
2. Added an additional filter to Main query that brought the results down to the same level
3. Missing a comparison in the sub-query back to the month column

Here is the final query:

```
    SELECT
    Area_NM,
    [1] AS Jan,
    [2] AS Feb,
    [3] AS Mar,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS May,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Oct,
    [11] AS Nov,
    [12] AS Dec
FROM
(select DISTINCT Area_NM, month(Closed_DT) as TMonth, (100 * 

    (
        select COUNT(*) from T_AREA AS DISP
        WHERE P.Area_NM = DISP.Area_NM AND month(P.Closed_DT) = month(DISP.Closed_DT) AND DISP.Branch_MKT = 'NORTHEAST' AND DISP.About <> 'Branch' AND DISP.CAP_TXT IS NOT NULL
    )  
     /  
    (  
        select sum(count(*)) over () from T_AREA AS TOT
        WHERE P.Area_NM = TOT.Area_NM AND month(P.Closed_DT) = month(TOT.Closed_DT) AND TOT.Branch_MKT = 'NORTHEAST' AND TOT.About <> 'Branch'
        ) 

     ) as perc
    from T_AREA AS P
    WHERE P.Branch_MKT = 'NORTHEAST' AND P.About <> 'Branch' AND P.CAP_TXT IS NOT NULL

    ) source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(perc)
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvtMonth
```